# How do I strip part of a file name?

Tags: powershell

Suppose I have a file `database_partial.xml`.

I am trying to strip the file from "_partial" as well as extension (xml) and then capitalize the name so that it becomes `DATABASE`.

```
Param($xmlfile)

$xml = Get-ChildItem "C:\Files" -Filter "$xmlfile"

$db = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($xml).ToUpper()
```

That returns `DATABASE_PARTIAL`, but I don't know how to strip the _PARTIAL part.

Comment: Replace could be used:
$db = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($xml).ToUpper() -replace "_PARTIAL"

Comment: @jfrmilner shouldnt it be replace with something? like replace with ""

Comment: replace with a single parameter will remove/strip

Comment: @jfrmilner single parameter? so you mean by default replace will remove the _partial and replace it with nothing right?

Comment: correct, try "DATABASE_PARTIAL" -replace "_PARTIAL"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` for removing the extension. The `FileInfo` objects returned by `Get-ChildItem` have a property `BaseName` that gives you the filename without extension. Uppercase that, then remove the "_PARTIAL" suffix. I would also recommend processing the output of `Get-ChildItem` in a loop, just in case it doesn't return exactly one result.

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Files" -Filter "$xmlfile" | ForEach-Object {
    $_.BaseName.ToUpper().Replace('_PARTIAL', '')
}
```

If the substring after the underscore can vary, use a regular expression replacement instead of a string replacement, e.g. like this:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Files" -Filter "$xmlfile" | ForEach-Object {
    $_.BaseName.ToUpper() -replace '_[^_]*$'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Ansgar Wiechers's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) provides an effective solution.

To focus on the more general question of **how to strip (remove) part of a file name (string)**:

Use PowerShell's [**`-replace`** operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#replacement-operator), whose syntax is:
`<stringOrStrings> -replace <regex>, <replacement>`:

- `<regex>` is a *regex* ([regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions)) that matches the part to replace,
- `<replacement>` is *replacement operand* (the string to replace what the regex matched).

  - In order to effectively *remove* what the regex matched, specify `''` (the empty string) or simply *omit* the operand altogether - in either case, the matched part is effectively *removed* from the input string.

<sup>For more information about `-replace`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375).</sup>

Applied to your case:

```sh
$db = 'DATABASE_PARTIAL' # sample input value

PS> $db -replace '_PARTIAL$', ''  # removes suffix '_PARTIAL' from the end (^)
DATABASE

PS> $db -replace '_PARTIAL$'      # ditto, with '' implied as the replacement string.
DATABASE
```

Note:

- `-replace` is case-*insensitive* by default, as are all PowerShell operators. To explicitly perform case-*sensitive* matching, use the `-creplace` variant.
- By contrast, the `[string]` type's [`.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace) method (e.g., `$db.Replace('_PARTIAL', '')`:

  - matches by *string literals* only, and therefore offers less flexibility; in this case, you couldn't stipulate that `_PARTIAL` should only be matched at the *end* of the string, for instance.
  - is *invariably* case-*sensitive* in the .NET Framework (though .NET *Core* offers a case-insensitive overload).

---

Building on Ansgar's answer, your script can therefore be streamlined as follows:

```sh
Param($xmlfile)

$db = ((Get-ChildItem C:\Files -Filter $xmlfile).BaseName -replace '_PARTIAL$').ToUpper()
```

Note that in PSv3+ this works even if `$xmlfile` should match *multiple* files, due to [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) and the ability of `-replace` to accept an *array* of strings as input, the desired substring removal would be performed on the base names of *all* files, as would the subsequent uppercasing - `$db` would then receive an *array* of stripped base names.